# Localization in .NET 7 cannot find resource

Tags: c#, .net, api, localization

I have .NET 7 solution and inside it I have WebAPI project and class libraries.

My WebAPI project is called "Api.Gateway" and I created class library "Api.Localization".
Inside Api.Localization project I created Resources folder and added resx files and a class:
[image]

Inside the Project.cs file located in "Api.Gateway" project, I added localization `services.AddLocalization();`

I tried to add localization with `services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");` and also by adding the full path to Resources folder, but it did not work

In constructor of my controller I add `IStringLocalizer<Localization.Resources.Common> stringLocalizer` and when I try to get the localization string `_stringLocalizer["Test"]` I get that the location was not found.

Answer (score 0):

I actually fixed this issue by removing the class "Common" and I created the "Common" resx file.[image]